# Prestashop 1 Language URL

Tags: .htaccess, prestashop

Prestashop V:1.5.4.1, Front-end language: Swedish, Back-end language: English

Because I choose to have different languages between front and back-end, current language setup will show the SEO friendly language URL "/sv" in the store, even though I only have and will always have only Swedish in the front end.

How can I make the language specific URL disappear in the front-end even though I have multiple languages installed, but only for use in the back-end?

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the Link class.
Create a new file /override/classes/Link.php with the following content:

```
<?php

class Link extends LinkCore
{
    protected function getLangLink($id_lang = null, Context $context = null)
    {
        return '/';
    }
}
```

Do not forget to remove the /cache/class_index.php file (which is a cache for the override file).

Answer (score 0):

For Prestashop 1.6.xx

```
<?php

class Link extends LinkCore
{
    protected function getLangLink($id_lang = null, Context $context = null, $id_shop = null)
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```